# Nested if command or if with two conditions in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to write a bind for a copy command where I want to test for tmux version and operating system. If tmux version is less than 2.4 and using Linux do one thing and with Mac another and same for greater than version 2.4.

If Linux:

```
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.4" | bc)" = 1 ]' " \
    bind-key -t vi-copy y   copy-pipe 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'" " \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y   send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'"
```

If Mac:

```
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.4" | bc)" = 1 ]' " \
    bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy" " \
    bind -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'"
```

Comment: ...and what is your actual question?

Comment: If an if-shell can have two conditions or can be nested and how is that done? You could read the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-a` in your test:

```
if '[ "blah" = 1 -a "$(uname)" = Linux ]' ...
```

Or each argument to if-shell is a tmux command so you can nest them:

```
if 'true' 'if "true" "whatever"'
```